# How to extract specific data from a large .txt file, and print it while run time?

Tags: java, eclipse

So in this problem, we have a file with a lot data based on drivers which includes license number, license class, firstName, lastName, address, suburb, postcode, demerit points and license status. And the question is to print only those sets of data that have a license status of suspended. And it has to be printed with license number, firstName, lastName, address, suburb and demerit points.

I have tried print the whole file first then allocating them into seperate memory files. Then using .equalsIgnoreCase("Suspended") tried to print only the suspended data sets.

First Attempt:

```
try {
      File inFile  = new File("Driver.txt");
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(inFile);

      String value;
      String[] values;

      while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        value = inputFile.nextLine();
        values = value.split(",");
          System.out.println("Licence Number: " + "\t" + values[0]);
          System.out.println("First Name:" + "\t" + "\t"  +  values[2]);
          System.out.println("Last Name: " + "\t" + "\t"  +  values[3]);
          System.out.println("Suburb: " + "\t" + "\t" +  values[5]);
          System.out.println("Demerit Points: " + "\t" +  values[7]);
          System.out.println("Licence Status: " + "\t" +  values[8]);
          System.out.println();

          String licenceStatus = null;
          values[8] = licenceStatus;
          System.out.println(licenceStatus);

          System.out.println();

          /*if (licenceStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Suspended")) {
            System.out.println("Listed below are the currently suspended drivers. ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Licence Number: " + "\t" + values[0] );
            System.out.println("First Name:" + "\t" + "\t" + values[2]);
            System.out.println("Last Name: " + "\t" + "\t" + values[3]);
            System.out.println("Address: " + "\t" + "\t" + values[4] );
            System.out.println("Suburb: " + "\t" + "\t" + values[5]);
            System.out.println("Demerit Points: " + "\t" + values[7]);
            System.out.println();
          } */

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("File not found!");
     }


Second Attempt:

try {
      File inFile  = new File("Driver.txt");
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(inFile);

      while (inputFile.hasNext()) {

          String licenceNumber = inputFile.next();
          System.out.println("Licence Number: " + licenceNumber + " ");

          String licenceClass = inputFile.next();
          System.out.println("Licence Class: " + licenceClass + " ");

          String firstName = inputFile.next();
          System.out.println("First Name:" + firstName + " ");

          String lastName = inputFile.next();
          System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName + " ");

          String address = inputFile.next();
          System.out.println("Address: " + address + " ");

          String suburb = inputFile.next();
          System.out.println("Suburb: " + suburb + " ");

          int postCode = inputFile.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Postcode: " + postCode + " ");

          int demeritPoints = inputFile.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Demerit Points: " + demeritPoints + " ");

          String licenceStatus = inputFile.next();
          System.out.println("Licence Status: " + licenceStatus + " ");

          System.out.println();

         /* if (licenceStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Suspended")) {
            System.out.println("Listed below are the currently suspended drivers. ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Licence Number: " + "\t" + `enter code here`licenceNumber );
            System.out.println("First Name:" + "\t" + "\t" + firstName);
            System.out.println("Last Name: " + "\t" + "\t" + lastName);
            System.out.println("Address: " + "\t" + "\t" + address );
            System.out.println("Suburb: " + "\t" + "\t" + suburb);
            System.out.println("Demerit Points: " + "\t" + demeritPoints);
            System.out.println();
          } */ 

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("File not found!");
      }
```

It should print like:

License Number: ########
First Name: ########
Last Name: ########
Address:########
Suburb:#######
Demerit Points: ##

Comment: You've shown us what you tried and what the output _should_ look like, but you didn't really explain what the problem is.  And it certainly doesn't help that the code meant to print the "suspended" drivers has been entirely commented out...

Comment: Yes I understand, the suspended code was commented out because I was trying to work out how to print them in the order. But I have got the solution and it works! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like

```
if (values[8].equals("Suspended")) {
      System.out.println("Licence Number: " + "\t" + values[0]);
      System.out.println("First Name:" + "\t" + "\t"  +  values[2]);
      System.out.println("Last Name: " + "\t" + "\t"  +  values[3]);
      System.out.println("Suburb: " + "\t" + "\t" +  values[5]);
      System.out.println("Demerit Points: " + "\t" +  values[7]);
      System.out.println("Licence Status: " + "\t" +  values[8]);
      System.out.println();
}
```